# Set validity 20 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried to create a validity using javascript timer for more than 1 minute, but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
function timer(){
    var epoch = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000.0);
    var countDown = 6000 - (epoch % 1000);
    if (epoch % 6000 == 0) updateOtp();
    $('#updatingIn').text(countDown);
}

$(function () {
    updateOtp();
    $('#secret').keyup(function () {
        updateOtp();
    });
    setInterval(timer, 10000);
});
```

My actually goal is to make it to 20 minutes within the countdown in minutes.

Thanks for any suggestion link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reduce timer call to 1 second

```
setInterval(timer, 1000)
```

and change 6000 to 1200 (seconds number in 20 minutes)